# Django: Best practice with Foreignkeys and multiple models

Tags: django, data-structures, foreign-keys, abstract-class, foreign-key-relationship

Hi Stackoverflow people,

What is the best way to refer from one model to a choice of ForeignKeys?

I am working on a rental app, which includes a model for the GenericVehicle, Bikes, and Cars.

```
class GenericVehicle(models.Model):
    licence = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Bike(GenericVehicle):
    engine_type = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ...

class Car(GenericVehicle):
    number_of_doors = models.SmallIntegerField()
    ...
```

Now I have a model for the rental registration, where I would like to register the rented vehicle. I am unsure about the best practise here. So far, I had two foreignkeys and made sure that at least one is filled. But this solution seems very inefficient and does not scale well for multiple vehicle types.

**What is the best way to improve the class structure/definition?**

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    rental_bike = models.ForeignKey(Bike)
    rental_car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    rental_date = ...
```

Thank you for your advice. I am trying to find an efficient solution for some time already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django offers you a [`GenericForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1). A `GenericForeignKey` will need to fields on you model, one for saving the referenced model's `ContentType` and a second one to save the object's id:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class Rental(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    rental_vehicle = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

But keep in mind that this not a foreign key on database level, just Django kind of emulating some of the typical behaviour of a foreign key.